# Manage stock needs to be set per store

Tags: magento2, multistore, stock

Situation:

Magento 2.4.2 p1  (but was also like this on earlier versions)

We have Magento multistore.

So example.

I create a configurable product from our imports (Emagic manager).
I set ‘manage stock’ for the default value of the configurable product to ‘no’
Now as ‘manage stock’ is a global setting I would expect the manage stock also to be not on different store view.

However, the change is only made for the default store and not for any other store.

Running indexes etc do not work.

So now we need to manually open the configurable product. Change to a different store view and set the manage stock to ‘no’ for that store.

How can we get the managed stock to get working on all store views as it is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure stock by store by switching stores at the top of the page
https://nimb.ws/c5sfEj